# Unusual rendering artifact

Tags: rendering

I was playing around with the sapling tree gen add-on in blender 2.8 when I noticed that the render was obscured by this large fog-like object. This is happening both with eevee and cycles. I did not create any geometry beyond a cube for background, the leaves and a second tree trunk because for some reason, I lost the trunk after baking animation.

For full disclosure, I was playing with 2.8 while rendering and animation with cycles on another instance of 2.9 on my computer (i.e. I was running two versions of blender at the same time).

Screen grabs follow:

[image: the rendered tree, with the background cube disabled]

---

Thanks for offering help. I checked all the stuff and didn’t find anything connected to the volume in the output nodes of any of the shaders.

As suggested, here’s the source file.

> [Blend file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRhrW.jpg)

Comment: Make sure nothing is connected to the volume output of the material node tree

Comment: if Gorgious answer doen't help, please provide blend file

Comment: Again, thanks for helping. I started a new project file and it rendered just fine. I think I got the wrong tree parameters the first time around. Maybe the tree truck was scaled so large that the entire scene was contained inside it.